# pandas DataFrame KeyError: get list of missing keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exception, keyerror

I am trying to select from the data frame `df` the rows that match a list of keys  `IDs`.

```
df.loc[IDs]
```

In rare cases they keys are not contained in the DataFrame and a KeyError is thrown:

```
KeyError: "None of [['001U000001c6OczIAE' '001U000000fgVR9IAM' '0015800000ecNcjAAE'\n '001U000000fgVRDIA2']] are in the [index]"
```

Can I easily get to the list of missing keys from that exception? Would it be better/cleaner/more pythonic to not do this by exception handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more info it looks like you may have forgotten a step- have you set your index to the Salesforce ID (assuming that's what it is)?

For example (random data):

```
df
    a account
0   1     abc
1   3     abc
2   5     abc
3   7     def
4   7     def
5  34      gf
6   3      hj
7  24      hj

lis = ['abc', 'hj']
df.loc[lis]
KeyError: "None of [['abc', 'hj']] are in the [index]"
```

**For pandas versions prior to 0.21.0**

After setting index:

```
df.set_index('account').loc[lis]
          a
account    
abc       1
abc       3
abc       5
hj        3
hj       24
```

Missing values should not throw an error, rather `np.nan` value:

```
lis = ['abc', 'hj', 'j']
df.set_index('account').loc[lis]
            a
account      
abc       1.0
abc       3.0
abc       5.0
hj        3.0
hj       24.0
j         NaN
```

**For pandas versions 0.21.0+**

You will need to instead use the dataframe method `reindex()`. With reindex, however, you will not be able to have duplicates in the index (so my example above will not work without some deduplication):

```
df.set_index('account')\
.groupby(level=0).first()\  # de-duplicate index here
.reindex(lis2)

           a
account     
abc      1.0
hj       3.0
j        NaN
```

Unfortunately using `reindex()` after deduplicating there is data loss if you're trying to continue working with the dataframe. Regardless, this is probably not the best way to find identifiers missing from your dataframe.

Comment: That's weird, I think I set the index correctly by passing `index_col=...` to `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: What's the output of `df.head()`? Are there duplicates in the index?

Comment: Can't show the dataframe, but indeed there are some duplicates in the index, unexpectedly. Why is there no complaint when trying to make that column an index?

Comment: Strange- my duplicates theory was incorrect as I've just imported a test csv without any issue. If you view the dataframe after importing does it correctly have the IDs in the index?

Comment: It has the IDs in the index.

Comment: The only other way I can replicate this is if literally every value in the list is not in the index.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the case.

Comment: Easy enough- `except KeyError:` `print(IDs)`... You know the whole list is missing from `index`.

Comment: This feature has now been deprecated: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated